# Parsing Insert SQL Query in Java using Regular Expression

Tags: java, sql, regex

I want to parse the Insert Query in Java using Regex.

Following is the sample string

```
    INSERT INTO table_name (c1,c2,c3) VALUES (abc,def,ghi) , (jkl,mno,pqr)
```

I want the following output:

```
Group1: table_name  
Group2: c1,c2,c3    
Group3: abc,def,ghi
Group4: jkl,mno,pqr
```

I have tried the following regular Expression:

```
    INSERT INTO ([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_-]*) (?:\((.*)\))?\s*VALUES (\((,)?(.*)\))*
```

The output is

```
Group1 : table_name
Group2 : c1,c2,c3
Group3 : (abc,def,ghi) , (jkl,mno,pqr)
Group4 : Empty
Group5 : abc,def,ghi) , (jkl,mno,pqr
```

Please help me how to get the desired result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this regex:

`((?<=(INSERT\\sINTO\\s))[\\w\\d_]+(?=\\s+))|((?<=\\()(\\s*[\\w\\d_,]+\\s*)+(?=\\)))`

*Explanation:*

`(?<=(INSERT\\sINTO\\s))[\\w\\d_]+(?=\\s+)` matches `[\\w\\d_]+` between `(INSERT\\sINTO\\s)` and `\\s+`

`(?<=\\()(\\s*[\\w\\d_,]+\\s*)+(?=\\))` matches `[\\w\\d_,]+` between `\\(` and `\\)`

Here is an example code:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String []args){
        String test = "INSERT INTO table_name (c1,c2,c3) VALUES (abc,def,ghi) , (jkl,mno,pqr)";

        String regex = "((?<=(INSERT\\sINTO\\s))[\\w\\d_]+(?=\\s+))|((?<=\\()([\\w\\d_,]+)+(?=\\)))";

        Pattern re = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        Matcher m = re.matcher(test);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(0));
        }
     }
}
```

The output is like:

```
table_name
c1,c2,c3
abc,def,ghi
jkl,mno,pqr
```

Comment: Ty Never thought of using Look Behind functionality of Regex.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works

```
(INSERT INTO) (\S+).*\((.*?)\).*(VALUES).*\((.*?)\)(.*\;?)
```

https://regex101.com/r/0wsoqJ/4

Answer (score 0):

For this specific example of your query, the following regex should do the trick.

`INSERT INTO (\S+) \((\S+)\) VALUES \((\S+)\) , \((\S+)\)`

https://regex101.com/r/2Kdayp/1

Comment: I want a solution for parsing a generic insert query.