# Insert SQL Query in Java using Regular Expression to get it's parts

Tags: java, regex

I have a statement:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (c1,c2,c3) VALUES ('',N'user','','1970-01-01 00:00:00.0')
```

I would like to create a regex that running will give me following result:

```
table_name
c1,c2,c3
'',N'user','','1970-01-01 00:00:00.0'
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40879952/parsing-insert-sql-query-in-java-using-regular-expression) question and answer I've created something like this:

```
final String regex = "((?<=(INSERT\\sINTO\\s))[\\w\\d_]+(?=\\s+))|((?<=\\()([\\w\\d_,]*|[N?'?.*\\s?.*'?,]*)+(?=\\)))";
```

However, my answer is only:

```
table_name
c1,c2,c3
'',N'user',''
```

Could you please help me and tell what I'm doing wrong?

My code to test:

```
final String regex = "((?<=(INSERT\\sINTO\\s))[\\w\\d_]+(?=\\s+))|((?<=\\()([\\w\\d_,]*|[N?'?.*\\s?.*'?,]*)+(?=\\)))";

        String test = "INSERT INTO table_name (c1,c2,c3) VALUES ('',N'user','','1970-01-01 00:00:00.0')";

        Pattern re = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        Matcher m = re.matcher(test);
        while (m.find())
        {
            System.out.println(m.group(0));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it! :)

```
((?<=(INSERT\\sINTO\\s))[\\w\\d_]+(?=\\s+))|((?<=\\()([\\w?\\d?_,]*|[(?:^|\\s)'([^']*?)'(?:$|\\s),]*)+(?=\\)))
```

Comment: Since i don't see the difference, it was a typo in the regex I would guess ?

Comment: No, there is a big difference in the second part: it used to be "[N?'?.*\\s?.*'?,]*", now it is "[(?:^|\\s)'([^']*?)'(?:$|\\s),]*"

Comment: Note that the quality of the initial regex is rather poor, and the modified version you made is even messier. Parsing SQL commands with a single pattern is not a good idea, you already got confused with matching a mere table name and substrings inside parentheses. Imagine how it gets more complex if you want to add another thing to match here. Besides, you misunderstand the character class and grouping construct concepts. Read about shorthand character classes, you will see that  `[\w\d_]` = `\w`, and `[\\w?\\d?_,]` = `[\\w?,]`.

Comment: Thanks for hint, I will pay more attention to that :)